# Python Matplotlib plotting prediction graph in wrong order

Tags: python, matplotlib, stock

I'm trying to predict a future stock price using a linear regression model, but there is a problem regarding the plotting of the prediction graph. Every time I run the code, the original graph plot (blue) is correct, but the prediction (green) and valid graph (orange) are in the wrong order. Also, the valid graph is red when it is supposed to be orange.

```
import requests # For http request to https://marketstack.com
import pandas as pd # For pandas datatable
import numpy as np

# Api Key
params = {
    'access_key': '****************************'
}

# Request Api Key Data
api_result = requests.get('https://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=************************&symbols=FB&interval=1min&sort=DESC&limit=1000', params)
api_response = api_result.json()

# Sorts the data into a table
df = pd.DataFrame(api_response['data'])
print(df)

# Exports and then imports csv data
df.to_csv('Test_Sample.csv', index=False)
dataframe = pd.read_csv('Test_Sample.csv', header=0)

#Reverse data table
dataframe2 = dataframe.iloc[::-1]
print(dataframe2)

#Convert string to floats
dataframe2['symbol']=pd.to_numeric(dataframe2['symbol'], errors='coerce')
dataframe2['exchange']=pd.to_numeric(dataframe2['exchange'], errors='coerce')
dataframe2['date']=pd.to_numeric(dataframe2['date'], errors='coerce')
dataframe2.info()

#Create target volume
dataframe2['Price_up'] = np.where(dataframe2['close'].shift(-1) > dataframe2['close'], 1, 0)

data = dataframe2[["close"]]
print(data.head())

#The number of days for prediction
futureDays = 30

data["prediction"] = data[["close"]].shift(-futureDays)
print(data.head())
print(data.tail())

import numpy as np
x = np.array(data.drop(["prediction"], 1))[:-futureDays]
print(x)

y = np.array(data["prediction"])[:-futureDays]
print(y)

#75% training data and 25% testing data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.25)

# creating the Linear Regression model
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linear = LinearRegression().fit(xtrain, ytrain)

xfuture = data.drop(["prediction"], 1)[:-futureDays]
xfuture = xfuture.tail(futureDays)
xfuture = np.array(xfuture)
print(xfuture)

linearPrediction = linear.predict(xfuture)
print("Linear regression Prediction =",linearPrediction)

#Correct chart appropriate way
sort_x = dataframe2['date']
sort_y = dataframe2['close']

#sort_x, sort_y = zip(*sorted(zip(sort_x, sort_y)))
#sort_x = dataframe2['date']
#sort_y = dataframe2['close']
sort_z = data['close']
sort_x, sort_y, sort_z = zip(*sorted(zip(sort_x, sort_y, sort_z)))

#Linear Regression Model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
predictions = linearPrediction
valid = data[x.shape[0]:]
valid["predictions"] = predictions
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.title("Financial Instrument Price Prediction Model (Linear Regression Model)")
plt.xlabel("Days")
plt.ylabel("Close Price")
plt.plot(sort_z)
plt.plot(sort_x, sort_y)
plt.plot(valid[["close", "predictions"]])
plt.legend(["Original", "Valid", "predictions"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

I've tried using the zip command (all the way at the button of the code) in order to reverse the graphs, but it only worked for the original one (blue). Does anyone have a suggesting on how I can fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: If you change the X axis to a series of integer values, I think you can draw the time series together. I don't have the API, so I created the graph with your code from yfinance.

Comment: Is it possible to hardcore the values of your plots here (or a subset of those) and trim down all that data fetching and fitting? Since we [can't replicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it anyway.

Comment: The actual code for the previous comment is as follows. `dataframe2.index=pd.to_numeric(np.arange(len(dataframe2)))`

Comment: @r-beginners thank you, worked right away! Do you know how I can change the color from red to orange, or is it not possible?

Comment: My graphs also show different results between the legend and the color of the lines. There are other ways to do this, try `plt.plot(. .color='C1')` or something like that. The color cycle is defined from C0 to C9. [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colors.html)